# How can I use DATEPART to return all rows with a specific year

Tags: sql, datepart

My database has a table 'Events'. Columns include 'name', 'Date' and 'Type
I want to run a query that returns all the event names of a given date AND type.

Firstly, how can I use the DATEPART to break up the date and allow it to be identified by the year.

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (DATEPART is not ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQL Server and that your 'Date' column is DATE or DATETIME data type, you can do this:

```
    SELECT GETDATE() -- i.e. will return 2015-11-25 11:27:27.700
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) -- returns 2015
```

So your query to get all events in 2015 for example, could look like this:

```
    SELECT Name, Date, Type 
    FROM Events
    WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,Date) = 2015 
    AND TYPE = <your type condition> 
    ORDER BY Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'datepart' function, this will be called for every row in your database, which can be costly.

It's better to select the year by using a range, then it can use indexes to search for the relevant rows in your database.

`select * from Events where [Date]>='1 jan 2015' and [Date]<'1 jan 2016' and [type]=1`